pip install したライブラリは何に紐づけられる？
VSCodeとPyCharmをインストールして、今二つのエディタを試しながら書いています。
例えば、VSCodeのコンソールで pip install pandas を実行し、pandas ライブラリをPCに入れたはずなのに、PyCharmでコードを実行すると「pandasが入っていない」という旨のメッセージが表示されてしまいます。
ライブラリというのは、PCそのものに入るというものではなく、エディタに紐づけられるものなのでしょうか？
例えば、WindowsのPowerShellで pip install pandas を実行した場合、同様にpandasというライブラリがインストールされると思いますが、これはどういうことでしょうか。
PowerShellでインストールされたpandasはどのエディタ用のものなのでしょうか。
PyCharmでも pip install pandas を実行したので、私のPCにはpandasのライブラリが二つ存在している、ということになるのでしょうか。
それとも、今書いているプログラムにのみ、ライブラリというのはインストールされているのでしょうか。
プログラムを勉強しはじめて、少し書いてみると、色々とライブラリを追加していくことになると思います。
段々、環境が汚れていくというか、どんなライブラリを入れたか、全て覚えていられないですし、精神衛生上、気持ちが悪いです。
私は、オフィスと自宅のデスクとで、PCが2台あるので、開発環境を統一したいという意図があり、上記の疑問に至っています。

Pythonをどのようにインストールしたのか？Python環境をマネジメントするツールを使用しているか？などの情報が不足しているかと思います。また、PyCharmはIDEでVSCodeはエディタですし、会社で使用されるならライセンスの確認も必要になるかと思います。

初心者あるあるで、多くのことに一度に手を出して収拾が付かなくなっているようですね。いったん立ち止まってPythonの一般的・基礎的な知識・使い方を系統的に学べるチュートリアルや学習コースをどれか一つ選んで、それを一度最後までやり通して見ることをお勧めします。いろんなことに手を出すのはそれからでも遅くないと思われます。おそらくそれぞれのツールの環境構築時に別々のPythonをインストールして複数存在している可能性が考えられます。Pythonディストリビューション使い分けのポイントを考えてみよう（Windows編）, Windowsでpyenv（pyenv-win）とvenvを使ってPythonの仮想環境を構築, 似ているようで意外と違う。venvとpyenvの使い分け。

VSCodeとPyCharmに関してはこちらの記事等で確認してみてください。Visual Studio Code を Python 用に設定する方法, Python インタープリターを構成する, vscode + python インタプリターを選択しても環境が切り替わらない, Module Not Found Error:No module named ‘django’これを解決するにはどうすればいいですか？

nekketsuuu様、すみません。どこにコメントすればよいのかわからないのでここに記述いたしますが、文章の修正、要約、ありがとうございます。大変わかりやすくなりました。拙い質問文で申し訳ございません。

kunif様　ご指摘の通り、収拾がつかなくなっている節があるのは事実です。ご紹介頂いたURL、一通り拝見しました。質問の意図と近いところの情報があり、勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。もう少し具体的なプロジェクトを１つ、自力で仕上げてみたいと思います。

Python の場合、ライブラリ（パッケージ）の実体はいくつかのファイルです。pip install を行ったとき、pip はパッケージを取得してきてどこかのディレクトリに格納します。
ところで、ひとつのパソコンの中に複数の独立した Python 環境を持たせることができます。このとき pip install したパッケージは別のディレクトリに保存されることになります。質問者さんの環境で、VS Code のコンソールで pip install したパッケージが PyCharm で認識されなかったのは、別の Python 環境を参照しているためでしょう。PyCharm はどの Python 環境を参照すべきか設定で変更できます: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter。
開発を進めて色々とパッケージを追加していく中で、今なにがどこにインストールされていてどれが使われることになるのか分からなくなりそう、というのはごもっともな疑問です。実際これは問題になるので、たとえばプロジェクトごとに Python の環境を切り替えて、そのプロジェクト固有のパッケージのみが使える状態でプログラムを実行できるようにする手法が知られています。Python 仮想環境や、パッケージ管理システムといったワードで知られています。
Python 自体や Python のパッケージを管理する仕組みはいくつか知られており、この回答を書いている時点では唯一絶対の標準は存在しません。PyCharm をお使いなら、Poetry のサポートがあるので最初はコレが分かりやすそうです: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/poetry.html。
こういった管理システムを使うと、どのバージョンのパッケージを使っているのかを列挙したファイルをプロジェクトごとに持つことになります。このファイルを使えば、異なるふたつのパソコンの間で Python の環境をなるべく揃えるのもラクになります。

nekketsuu様　コメントありがとうございます。質問の意図を繊細に汲み取って頂きありがとうございます。Windowsにおいても、スマホの「アプリ」においても「インストール」というと、重複して別々のものがインストールされるようなイメージがなく、しっくり来ていませんでした。
